# Audio crackling after update in USB sound card

Tags: sound, usb

With two USB sound cards (presonus audiobox and behringer xenyx q802) I have crackling sound after the kernel was updated to 5.13.0-37.
Tried on three different machines with Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.10.
Audio output from onboard audio is ok.
Output from USB sound card has irregular peaks (faster than every second).

I found this:

[Upgrading to 5.13.0-37-generic breaks audio with external audio card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398614/upgrading-to-5-13-0-37-generic-breaks-audio-with-external-audio-card)

which is very interesting, but doesn't tell what to do to get it working again.
I have no older kernels I could revert to. Any suggestions?

I mean, these were updates also for a LTS version that are not supposed to break a working system?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. If you can, [file a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121). Developers rely on bug reports to find, research, and fix bugs.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a bug, as stated in the above mentioned post: 
UPDATE: bug is reported by multiple users and Confirmed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.13/+bug/1966066

Because it seems like a fundamental problem I asked for detailed procedures to get it working again.

Comment: That's an even better reason to file a bug report. This will give developers more information to fix it. The more people a bug affects, the faster it will get fixed. In the meantime, when you boot Ubuntu, you can select the previous kernel version since it is unaffected.

Comment: Good point, will look into reporting the bug.
But for your suggestion, as I wrote:  > I have no older kernels I could revert to. 

So how do I set up a system with working audio? Tried to install 20.04.3 from here: <a>http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/ </a>, because it should come with kernel 5.11 (https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle)

Comment: But I ended up with the problematic kernel again (5.13, although automatic updates had been deactivated). Seems I miss a point or two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any older kernel, just install one using

```
sudo apt install linux-image-5.13.0-35-generic
```

(the 5.13.0-35 works for me). It seems that next upgrade 5.13.0-41 is a fix.

Comment: Don't forget to install linux headers too: sudo apt install linux-headers-5.13.0-35-generic

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` you should have a line like this

```
 ; default-sample-rate = 44100
```

edit the file with `sudo nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf` (don't forget to remove the `;` as it comments the line) to

```
default-sample-rate = 48000
```

save the file using `Ctrl+X` then `Yes` and press `Enter`

afterwards run

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service
```

Audio should work now.

You can find older kernel versions from the grub menu under `Advanced options for Ubuntu`

[image]

Comment: Hello. what does this last bit have to do with the answer? You can find older kernel versions from the grub menu under Advanced options for Ubuntu

Comment: That doesn't work in many cases, although the default setting  of 48kHz was marked as the correct answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398614/upgrading-to-5-13-0-37-generic-breaks-audio-with-external-audio-card

Comment: For the last bit of this answer: Actually the only thing that works is rolling back to linux-image-5.13.0-35. But I posted the question: what to do if I have no older kernel? I.e. want a fresh, non-LTS installation?